# Best approach to set up PHP and Java application on same host

Tags: apache, playframework, virtualhost, web-hosting

I have two web applications one in PHP and one in Java (Play framework).

I want to make both these applications available to my clients and I have only one server for test environment.

What would be the best and easy to maintain approach for my problem?

I am already looking at options of virtual hosts on Apache server. But is the best? Are there any third party tools which can help me to divert traffic to PHP and Java apps based on the port in the http request?

Port nos for PHP app is 80 and Java app is 9000.

Regards,
Suraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comment.

Yeah, I did the same thing. I am simply pointing my domain name to Apache Http server. So its using default port 80 and does not show up in urls.

Also, I am using Apache as front server for all my requests to port 9000. So, I am rerouting my requests for Play application at port 9000 through Apache port 80. It needed a change in url patterns so that play and apache specific urls can be distinguished.

Changed urls and used proxy_http_module + ProxyPassMatch directive to get the rerouting working.

Suraj

Answer (score 0):

assuming both ports are forwarded correctly and Apache is only listening for traffic on port 80 and java is only listening on 9000 then going to   YourIp:80 should take you to apache and YourIP:9000 should take you to the java app

Comment: I don't want to use port numbers in my urls.

Comment: When you set up a domain name you would point it to  IP:port number
for example 131.23.141.12:80 so once the domain  "www.MyDomain.com is pointed to the port you will not see the port number in your url

Answer (score 0):

For PHP app create common **vhost** as usally, and for Play app create reverse-proxy vhost (with other domain and/or subdomain for this), take a look at [samples in docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/HTTPServer)

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
...

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/your/php/app/root/folder/"
    ServerName your-php-app.com
    ErrorLog "/path/to/apache/logs/folder/your-php-app.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/path/to/apache/logs/folder/your-php-app.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName your-play-app.com
    ProxyPass  /excluded !
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: For my PHP and Java application, the domain name is same. Only port numbers are different. So, PHP (Apache) is listening at www.mydomain.com:80 and Java framework is listening at www.mydomain.com:9000. Further paths to controller and actions are different. E.g. www.mydomain.com:80/customer/profile and www.mydomain.com:9000/api/order. How can I configure virtual hosts in Apache for receiving traffic for www.mydomain.com:9000/api/order at port 80 and routing it to my Java application at port 9000?

Comment: Objective is to make both applications listen at port 80 and traffic routed to corresponding apps based on controller/action so that port numbers 9000 can be removed from java application urls.